# Print values of a Matrix C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I wrote this code that is composed of two files: main.cpp and matrice.cpp.

My problem is: the matrix does not write the values ​​in place that I indicate. I want you to write on the main diagonal all 1: A[i][i]= 1; but the result is different.

*What is the error? 
Why, when I print out the value of the matrix, appear 6.86636e-44?*

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrice.h"
#include "stampaMatrice.h"


using namespace std;
#define N 10
#define Inizio 0.00
#define Fine 1.00

float dy=(Fine-Inizio)/N;

int main()
{
    float ** A = matrice(dy, N);
    stampaMatrice(&A[0][0],N,N);

    //Clean up array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          { delete [] A[i]; }
    delete [] A;
    A = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

matrice.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float** matrice(float dy, int N){

float** A=0;
A=  new float*[N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
A[i]=new float[N];
}

//Assegnazione valori
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
//A[i][i+1]=1;
//A[i][i-1]=1/dy;
A[i][i]=1;

}


return A;
}
```

Result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5EeH.png)

Comment: Can we have enough code to reproduce the problem? The output code is missing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz There is a link to the output (see "Result" at the bottom of the question), although this is not the way to post the error/issue on StackOverflow. To OP, please post the error message directly or issue you're having directly on this site, without the need for an external link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misreading your results. All the values on the main diagonal are 1 just as you set them. Look closely.

You didn't set the values off the main diagonal to any particular value. So there's no reason you should expect any particular values. You'll get whatever junk happens to be there.

Comment: Well, that output seems pretty messed up to me (the only 1 in the right position is the first)... Maybe a look to `stampaMatrice()` to see how those numbers are printed could reveal other bugs.

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah, that's because `N=12` and the whole thing is shifted etc since probably OP didn't use any `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the off-diagonal elements to zero. C++ **does not** perform zero-initialization if you don't explicitly say so.

BTW, `float** A=0;` **does not set the elements of the matrix to zero**. You happen to get lots of zeros as this is what probably lied at those memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

"Fixing" this is easy: just change

```
A[i]=new float[N];
```

to

```
A[i]=new float[N]();
```

Now you have all the quirks of C++ in just 20 lines of code.